# Netherlands: is EUR 53000 salary enough for a family of 4?

Tags: netherlands

Is an annaul salary of EUR 53000 (before tax) sufficient for a family to live in Eindhoven area? It is a family of four with two school-going kids under 12.

Assuming the case of not getting the benefit of 30% ruling (or all foreign workers get it?), considering not a lavish but sort of frugal lifestyle, expenses like initial rental deposit, 2 bedroom house rental, transportation, utilities, school fees (I heard English schools are very expensive!), insurance, local govt/municipal taxes if any, and any other mandatory expenses, would there be anything left to save?

Given all that and if the job contract is for a year or so, is it okay to move the family or better stay alone? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Some numbers:

- The average Dutch salary in The Netherlands in 2014 is €35.000/yr ([source](http://hoegeldmaken.nl/geldzaken/wat-het-gemiddeld-salaris-nederland/))
- The modal Dutch salary in The Netherlands in 2015 is €35.500/yr  ([source](http://www.gemiddeld-inkomen.nl/modaal-inkomen-2015/))
- The modal Dutch salary in The Netherlands in 2016 is €36.500/yr  ([source](http://www.gemiddeld-inkomen.nl/modaal-inkomen-2016/))
- The average income *per household* for 2 adults + 2 kids under 18 in 2011 was €82,400 ([source](http://modaal-inkomen.nl/meer-cijfers))

A lot of extra information can be found [Googling for "Cost of living in The Netherlands"](https://www.google.nl/search?q=cost+of+living+in+the+netherlands)

[Numbeo](http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/country_result.jsp?country=Netherlands) gives a detailed list of sample items (note: no research data, just user contributed info). They claim:

> Cost of living in Netherlands is 1.82% higher than in United States (aggregate data for all cities, rent is not taken into account). Rent in Netherlands is 14.65% lower than in United States (average data for all cities).

Some remarks from [ExpatArrivals](http://www.expatarrivals.com/the-netherlands/cost-of-living-in-the-netherlands):

> Expats living in the Netherlands must purchase health insurance from a Dutch provider. Costs vary depending on the package chosen but can range from around 100 to 350 EUR and up.
>   Liability insurance, which is usually included in household insurance, is also a must. If a person, their child or their dog damages anybody else’s property they will be held responsible and will be expected to have this
>   Tuition at local schools is free, but international schools are expensive, and can easily cost 15,000 EUR per year.

In Eindhoven, [there seems to be only one international school](http://www.expatica.com/nl/education/Listing-of-international-schools-in-the-Netherlands_102018.html). This is what they say about their [tuition](http://www.isecampus.nl/Flex/Site/Page.aspx?PageID=7314):

- Primary school fees are only (a minimum of) €450. Formally speaking this is a voluntary contribution, but you can't really not pay this.
- Secondary schools are a different story: That's €6500 and not voluntary.

[Expatistan](https://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living/country/netherlands) has a 'Cost of living index' which shows you that you are 17% cheaper of in Eindhoven than in Amsterdam ;-)

Since many households live on one salary, and your kids are still in primary school, your number sounds 'doable'. I would hesitate if they were in secondary school.

But it's your decision (also based on non-financial arguments). Make a list of monthly expenses and decide based on that.

Comment: So, I'd say it's not enough, but it's what people make do with...